# Should I use IIFE in useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, iife

Is it good practice to use IIFE in useEffect or I should declare async function and then call it?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
      );
      const json = await response.json();

      setPosts(json);
    })();
  });
```

Comment: You can leave IIFE it should not have any issues with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As many of you may already know, you cannot pass an async function to the useEffect hook in React. Because of IIFE’s in a roundabout way we still can

You will see for our useEffect hook that we are able to use async-await syntax by using an IIFE. That’s really it. It’s that simple. IIFEs unlock the potential to use async-await syntax inside the useeffect hook.

**Conclusion**
IIFE’s are a really powerful JavaScript coding practice that comes in handy for a lot of different use-cases. It turns out that useEffect is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

I would advocate against it if you somehow interact with your components' state (useState).

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/lhj7nb/batching_usestate_in_async_useeffect/

```
     const result = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
      ); 
     result.then((json) => setPosts(json))
  }
```

No it is definitelly not.
You will mess around a lot with the way things work for react under the hood. Don't get carried away about what has been said before.

If you want to fetch posts based on some reaction, the right away for it would be to have your useEffect react to the desired state.

like userReachEndPage state would suit a useEffect(() => fetch ,[userReachEndPage])
If you were to react from a button then maybe wrap it in a callback, to avoid the extra rerender.

Never would be the right answer as to using IIF inside useeffect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using IIFE rather than declaring async function and calling it. coz you are going to use the declared async function only once in the useEffect and its precisely the use case for IIFE.